# User inputs to sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Script with the following line

> declare @input varchar(20)
>   Select * from Employees where [dept] =
>   @input

What I want is When I execute the above script in SQL 2005 I want to prompt for an input By opening an inputbox etc., such that the value is accepted in '@input' variable and so the user retrieves the records giving dynamic inputs.

Comment: SQL is SQL. The RDBMS doesn't prompt the user, it performs given queries written in SQL. You must be confusing it with Access, which is a hybrid between a document, GUI application and database.

Comment: +Unless you learn to !accept! given answers, you will receive few good ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The database doesn't have a user interface, so there are no means of prompting for a value.

You have to make an application that prompts for the value, queries the database and displays the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're really asking for a nonexistent feature but there are a few workarounds:

- SSRS allows you to define a "report" with parameters that will take the form of input boxes etc for your users.
- If you're ok with the users using SSMS, create the query as a stored procedure and have them use the execute option in the left-hand tree (this prompts for parameter inputs).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want
[Accepting User Input](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/SQL-Plus/Useaccepttogetuserinputvalueandusetheminaselectstatement.htm)

But it's for Oracle( ! ) . I hope this will work for other dbs also

Comment: Delete this answer. It's for Oracle. And it's a bad habit too.

Comment: `I hope this will work for other dbs also` - NO. it's a bad habit. RDBMS is a SERVER. it accepts connections, like an API. You give the request, receive the response. The SERVER can't make your PC (which may run a Mac OS, Linux, FreeBSD, Windows or whatever) to open up a dialog of some sort. It's just WRONG. It's missing the point, it's mixing up concerns. Unacceptable in any form.

Answer (score 0):

Or use C#; [Rapid Application Development Using SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition and Visual C#.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219483%28SQL.90%29.aspx)